# String Issue in Rest Assured Post

Tags: json, string, rest

```
    baseURI = ("");
   RestAssured.given()
           .contentType("application/json")
            .body(z.toString()
                   "{\n" +
                    "  \"address\": {\n" +
                    "    \"street\": \"AK Haq\",\n" +
                    "    \"country\": \"Pakistan\",\n" +
                    "    \"city\": \"Islamabad\",\n" +
                    "    \"postalCode\": \"J1J2J3\",\n" +
                    "    \"province\": \"KP\",\n" +
                    "    \"majorIntersection\": \"Test Major Intersection\"\n" +
                    "  },\n" +
                      "  \"name\":\" \"ABC\",\n" +
                      "  \"website\": \"www.mailinator.com.\",\n" +
                      "  \"description\": \"Test Description\",\n" +
                    "  \"isActivated\": false,\n" +
                    "  \"isInternal\": false,\n" +
                    "  \"abbreviation\": \"K\",\n" +
                    "  \"logo\": \"culpa sit\"\n" +
                    "}"
            ).post("").then()
            .log()
            .all()
            .assertThat()
            .statusCode(201);
```

It gives me the message name, website and description must be a string. I have passed the string but no result was achieved. In the Postman it works fine.